# How to check if a list of comma separated string values match an integer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Below I've added the SQL query.

I wanted retrieve the list of records that match a condition. I pass integer values into `@ClassID` and `@SectionID` parameters, The problem is `ce.Class_ID` and `ce.Section_ID` are lists of comma-separated string values.

```
SELECT ce.ID AS CircularEntryCount
FROM dbo.CircularEntry ce
WHERE ce.AcademicYearID = 1 
  AND (ce.Circular_Date = @CurrentDate OR CAST(ce.Created_Date AS date) = @CurrentDate)
  AND (ce.CircularApplicableForID = 1 OR ce.CircularApplicableForID = 3)
  AND (ce.Class_ID = @ClassID OR ce.Class_ID = '0') 
  AND (ce.Section_ID = @SectionID OR ce.Section_ID = '0')
```

PS: I used split string function to split the values into individual columns and compared the same with the parameters, but it shows.

> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint

```
(     
      @List nvarchar(2000),
      @SplitOn nvarchar(1)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table (
      Id int identity(1,1),
      Value nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
      While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
      Begin 
            Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
            Select 
                  Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1))) 
            Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
      End 

      Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
    Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

    Return
EN
```

Comment: Fix your data model, so you are not storing lists of integers in strings.  This is just the wrong way to store data.

Comment: Hint: `TRY_CAST()`

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'll pass that to my team mates. @GordonLinoff

Comment: It says 'TRY_CAST' is not a recognized built-in function name. @Sami

Comment: According to _"I used split string function"_ I thought you're using 2012+ version, and 2008 is out of support now.

Comment: Yeah I'm using MSSQL 2012, the function I used is a user defined one. @Sami

Comment: @Sase Show the query you tried when splitting your strings. Don't make this more difficult by not providing sufficient information. You should read Erland's discussion of [arrays and lists](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html#crackthelist) first to understand and learn how to approach this problem.

Comment: @SMor I've updated the Split String function that I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is to fix the problem - which means changing the structure of the database to not store delimited strings at all, but instead normalize the data and use foreign keys.
For more information, read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), and not only the accepted answer by Bill Karwin, but other answers as well.

In case you can't change the database structure, you can use a workaround using `like`:

```
SELECT ce.ID AS CircularEntryCount
FROM dbo.CircularEntry ce
WHERE ce.AcademicYearID = 1 
  AND (ce.Circular_Date = @CurrentDate OR CAST(ce.Created_Date AS date) = @CurrentDate)
  AND (ce.CircularApplicableForID = 1 OR ce.CircularApplicableForID = 3)
  AND (','+ ce.Class_ID +',' LIKE '%,'+ CAST(@ClassID as varchar(20)) +'%,' OR ce.Class_ID = '0') 
  AND (','+ ce.Section_ID +',' LIKE '%,'+ CAST(@SectionID as varchar(20)) +'%,' OR ce.Section_ID = '0')
```

Note the cast to `varchar(20)` - bigint's min value contains a minus sign and 19 digits. If the data type of `@ClassID` or `@SectionID` is int, you can cast to `varchar(11)` instead.